# pagerjs access url parameters in withOnShow

Tags: pagerjs

I'd like to (asynchronously) fetch model-data each time a page is shown. The path may have additional parameters telling the withOnShow-handler what fields to fetch, for example:

```
..#!/navigation/href_with_params/users/123?fields=a,b,c,d
```

How would you access the "fields"-param inside the withOnShow handler?

```
Cool.loadUser = function(callback, page) {
$.get('users/' + page.currentId + "?fields=" + <fields>, function(data) {
  callback(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like

```
var fields = page.ctx.field();
```

inside your `withOnShow`. Hope this helps.